# Regex issue. Not sure how to define step definition for (Then) in scenario

Tags: rspec, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Scenario Outline:  Verify Full ad details
    Given I am on the xxxxx classified home page
    And I have entered  in the search field & clicked on search
    When I click on full details
    Then I should see    <
    AdvertId>    <
    Headline>    <
    Description>    <
    CountryName>    <
    Price> 
    <
    ThumbnailImage>    <
    PartExchange>    <
    Phone>    <
    AltPhone>    <
    Location> displaying correctly and successfully

```
    Examples:
    |AdvertId|Headline|Description|CountryName|Price|ThumbnailImage|PartExchange|Phone|AltPhone|Location|
    |219|V12 Vantage Coupe|Powerfold mirrors,Alcantara steering wheel,HID projector headlamps,Electronic brakeforce distribution (EBD),LED rear lamps,Emergency brake assist (EBA),Aston Martin 160 W audio system,Dynamic stability control with Track mode (DSC),Electrically adjustable front seats,Trip computer,Tyre pressure monitoring,Bluetooth telephone preparation,Auto dimming interior rear view mirror,Memory seats and exterior mirrors,Ventilated, carbon ceramic disc brakes with ABS,Aluminium, magnesium alloy, composite and steel body,Side airbags (sports seats only),iPod integration and MP3 connectivity,Carbon fibre door pulls,Rear parking sensors,Hard Disk Drive (HDD) Satellite navigation system,Cruise control,Alarm and immobiliser,Boot-mounted umbrella,Dual stage driver and passenger front airbags|Costa Rica|99000|http://img.pistonheads.com.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Thumbnail/aston_martin/v12_vantage/aston_martin-v12_vantage-1012-1.jpg||08444119220||Costa Rica|
    |221|V8 Vantage Coupe 4.7|Side Airbags,Dynamic stability control (DSC),Ventilated, grooved disc brakes with ABS,Aston Martin 160 W audio system, Alarm and immobiliser,Emergency brake assist (EBA),Electronic brakeforce distribution (EBD),Rear parking sensors,6 CD autochanger,Electrically adjustable front seats,LED Rear Lamps,Dual stage driver and passenger front airbags,Tyre pressure monitoring,Trip computer,Full leather interior|Denmark|52906|http://img.pistonheads.com.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Thumbnail/aston_martin/v8_vantage/aston_martin-v8_vantage-966-1.jpg||08444119218||Denmark|
```

I need help in trying to define the step definition in appropriate regular expressions. Also in the scenario I have only displayed 2 examples. Is there a way to write only one line of code and step definition, which will work for any number of row examples?

Any answers to this desperate situation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that the regex can tell where one value ends and another one starts, you should add quotation marks around each value. So the step would be written as:

```
Then I should see "<AdvertId>" "<Headline>" "<Description>" "<CountryName>" "<Price>" "<ThumbnailImage>" "<PartExchange>" "<Phone>" "<AltPhone>" "<Location>" displaying correctly and successfully
```

Then you can easily match it using:

```
Then /I should see "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" "(.*)" displaying correctly and successfully/ do |advert_id, headline, description, country_name, price, thumbnail_image, part_exchange, phone, alt_phone, location|
```

Note that it does not matter how many examples you have. The only thing that matters is the content of your examples. The above should work unless you put quotations in one of the values.

An alternative is to write each check individually:

```
Then I should see the advert id "<AdvertID>" displaying correctly and successfully
Then I should see the headline "<Headline>" displaying correctly and successfully
etc
```

which is matched by:

```
Then /I should see the advert id "(.*)" displaying correctly and successfully/
Then /I should see the headline "(.*)" displaying correctly and successfully/
etc
```

Writing each individually makes it easier to figure out what fails and easier to write the regex. However, if the checks are not independent, a single step may be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I'm going to give this a go in the morning. I'll come back with some feedback. I think I was over complicating the issue by trying to add (\d+) (\w+) (.+) regexes into my step definition which were not working at all.

Comment: Thanks Justin, worked like a charm. I used your second example. Awesome